# Best practice for importing component from components library in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-modules

When I create components in React, they're all in a folder called `component` and each component has a dedicated folder with the same name as the component itself, e.g. `../components/Input`.

But a big concern is about naming files. In order to avoid having to long paths, I name the component inside the folder `Index.tsx` so that when I import, I'll only have `../components/Input` otherwise, it would be a very ugly import path like `../components/Input/Input`.

So, by naming `Index.tsx`, in my IDE, I end up having too much index files open and then I get lost.

So what I did was to rename all those components file with the same name as the folder `Input.tsx` and exporting them using named export like `export const Input:React.FC<InputProps>=(props)=>{...}`, then at the root of my component folder, I created one `index.tsx` file where I export all those components so that while importing them in my pages, I can just write `import {Input} from "../components"`.

I like this approach, but my next concern is about tree shaking. Because I don't want to import every time the entire components library.

So with the above approach, does React handle automatically tree shaking for us?

Answer (score 6):

There's [a tweet](https://twitter.com/iamakulov/status/1331551351214645251) about the possible issues related to re-exporting everything with index files.

> If your project has a `components/index.js` file which re-exports all your components (and does nothing else), that’s one example.
>
> This is bad for performance – for two reasons.
>
> 1. It makes code splitting ineffective.
>
>    When you do
>
>    ```
>    import { Button } from './components'
>    ```
>
>    you’re importing not only Button but the whole ‘./components’ file. Which means you’re *bundling* the whole file – with all the components it exports.
> 2. It makes bundle initialization more expensive.
>
>    Every time a browser downloads the bundle, it has to execute it – and all its modules as well. If there’re a lot of modules, or some of them do something expensive, this can take a while.

[Someone else](https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/1331909789207638017?s=20&t=HJLWnwYQhRdTSzCi3qwkAw) suggests configuring [webpack's `sideEffects` option](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free) so that the tree-shaking can still optimize the bundle as much as possible.

What I'm suggesting is to create small component modules inside the `components` directory.

```yaml
- components/
  - Input/          # component module
    - index.ts      # exports public API
    - Input.tsx     # actual component implementation
    - Input.test.tsx
    - Input.scss
    - Input.stories.tsx
    - etc.
```

Where the `index.ts` only re-export the *public* API for this component.

```
// index.ts
export { Input } from './Input';
export type { InputProps } from './Input';
// etc.
```

So that we have non-repeating paths when importing, but the filename we're actually working with is named according to the component.